# Why are there no parentheses after math.pi function call in python?

Tags: python

I am using python3.x .

I imported the math module and wanted to use the value of maths constant pi. However, python gives error on writing math.pi() but works on writing math.pi.

Similar issue was observed with z.real and z.imag (where z is acomplex number).
Are these some special kind of functions. If yes , what are they called?

Comment: `pi` is a constant, there is no reason it would be a function

Comment: What makes you think that `math.pi` (a constant value in our galaxy) should be a function?

Comment: math.pi is a constant not a function.

Comment: `math.pi` is neither a function nor a constant (in the programmatic context of the word). It is merely a module-level variable

Answer (score 0):

Because pi is a constant in the Math module, so its like youre just addressing an attribute of a class, not a function that returns the value of Pi

Comment: It is not a constant, it is merely a module-level variable, defined as `pi = 3.141592653589793` (line 18 on `math.py` in CPython 3.8). One can easily do `import math ; math.pi = 9`

Comment: Sure, what he said^

Comment: It's a variable only because Python doesn't support constants. Arguably a poor decision.

Comment: @jarmod it supports that where it really matters, eg built-in types' attributes (via c modules) or via slots. If someone really want to do `math.pi = 9`, let them be :D

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the docs, it shows the different constants in the math module

### Constants

- math.pi  : The mathematical constant π = 3.141592…, to available precision.
- math.e   : The mathematical constant e = 2.718281…, to available precision.
- math.tau : The mathematical constant τ = 6.283185…, to available precision. Tau is a circle constant equal to 2π, the ratio of a circle’s circumference to its radius. To learn more about Tau, check out Vi Hart’s video Pi is (still) Wrong, and start celebrating Tau day by eating twice as much pie!

  etc...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pi

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `math.pi` is not a method but an attribute; as it is a constant representing a value. Therefore, you should access it without using parentheses.

The correct way to access the value of pi is `math.pi`, not `math.pi()`.

As a reminder:

**Attribute:** A value associated with an object or class which is referenced by name using dot notation.

**Method:** A function that belongs to a class and typically performs an action or operation.